# how can i created a script with adb shell commands

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have been trying to add a wifi network with these commands inside a script:

```
adb shell wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0

# Get to wpa_cli prompt
adb shell wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0

# Add new WiFi network
adb shell add_network

adb shell set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN 
adb shell set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK 
adb shell set_network 0 ssid "Password" 
adb shell set_network 0 proto RSN
adb shell set_network 0 mode 0 
adb shell set_network 0 psk "Mynetwork name"

# Connect to it
adb shell select_network 0 
adb shell enable_network 0
adb shell reassociate 

# Check the status
adb shell status
```

but after the first command the terminal stays always in adb shell prompt and the other commands are not executed

Comment: Is `ssid "Password"` and  `psk "Mynetwork name"` intentional, or should these parameters be reversed?

Answer (score 1):

```
WPACLI="adb shell wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0"

# Add new WiFi network
NETWORK=$($WPACLI add_network)

$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK auth_alg OPEN 
$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK key_mgmt WPA-PSK 
$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK ssid "Password" 
$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK proto RSN
$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK mode 0 
$WPACLI set_network $NETWORK psk "Mynetwork name"

# Connect to it
$WPACLI select_network $NETWORK
$WPACLI enable_network $NETWORK
$WPACLI reassociate 

# Check the status
$WPACLI status
```

Comment: Agree with the answer, but worth mentioning WHY:
Each call to `adb shell` opens a new shell. It is not a way to interact with the same shell over and over again, and once you call `adb shell wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0`, without a command, `wpa_cli` will start in interactive mode and wait for your input. Specifying each command invokes wpa_cli in non interactive mode, thus returns to you directly.

Comment: Don't know if Is `ssid "Password"` and  `psk "Mynetwork name"` is intentional or is an oversight from the original poster.